# Android Navigation Drawer with imageview

Tags: java, android, mobile, navigation-drawer

I would like to know if there is a good tutorial so i can make a drawer like the two first in this image

http://www.vizteck.com/sites/default/files/navigation-drawer1.jpg

that have an image on the top of the list. I have tried using  imageview on the top of the list but without having the same result!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `DrawerLayout` with `ListView` and a custom Layout which has `ImageView` and `TextView`.

Check this link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html for how to use `DrawerLayout`.

Include the custom Layout above `ListView` as shown in the link.

You can use ExpandableListView if your list item has sub items.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the question is too broad.

Did you use http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html this to implement the drawer?

Did you use custom adapter instead of
     mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
?

In your custom adapter, you have custom layout to have imageview.
What I did was detect if it's the first item in the list, then have a different layout of the view which has an imageview and load image there.

I was going to post comment, but I don't have reputation yet.